# University awards degree, but asks for additional (not previously disclosed) requirements in order to recommend for certification

Tags: graduate-school

In my state, one way to earn a certification as an administrator for elementary and secondary education is to attend an educational administration program through a university in the state,  earn a masters degree through that program, and get a "**recommendation for certification from the designated official for educational administration at the college or university where the program was completed**". ([Source](https://dese.mo.gov/educator-quality/certification/become-certified-administrator).)

I, along with 9 others, recently completed our educational administration masters degree in a local cohort at a university in this state. We were awarded the degree, but the university will not recommend us for certification even though we have done everything asked of us for program completion.

We continually asked during the program what was going to be required and were told by multiple people employed by the university that they didn’t know what the changes were and for us to just wait. Now I have been told that we need to go back and pay money and take another class just to be recommended for certification from the university. I find this a little unreasonable having just met the requirements set forth by the university and having a masters degree in hand.

We have reached out to multiple people affiliated with the university who haven’t had the courtesy to even acknowledge receipt of our request.

What options are available to students in this scenario?

Comment: Welcome to AC.SE. I edited your question a little as we tend to frown upon calling out specific universities. I am not really sure what you are asking about, so if I made a mistake, feel free to fix it. Also, your question reads more like a rant than a question. You will get better answers if you can ask it more objectively. Also, you may want to take a look at our [help].

Comment: I tried to clarify your question, for the benefit of readers who are not people in the field of educational administration in the state of Missouri ;)

Comment: Having done that: it seems to me that they never promised to recommend for certification based on having completed the (then-in-place) requirements for the masters, they always disclosed that they didn't know yet exactly what you would need to do to be recommended for certification. Is that right, or am I misreading?

Comment: @ff524 I think your edits improve the question a lot.

Comment: The edits were extremely helpful, and I've retracted my close vote now that I understand the question.

Comment: We have met all requirements given to us by the university at the time we registered.  Several changes were made during the course of our program and communicating those changes was always a challenge.  The university has yet to update their current program to reflect the new changes.

Comment: Is it possible the original requirements were not sufficient by law?